# How to show a beanValidation class level constraint on a thymeleaf view?

Tags: spring, groovy, bean-validation, thymeleaf

I'm using bean validation(JSR303) to validate two fields, those fields are validate with an annotation and a validator, the annotation targeted the type that means the annotation is a class level constraint of my bean.
The question is how do I express the error on my view?
(I'm using groovy)
SignupForm :

```
package core.model

import core.validation.PasswordConfirmation
import core.validation.UniqueEmail
import core.validation.UniqueUsername
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank

import static core.model.AuthoritiesEnum.ROLE_USER

@Slf4j
@PasswordConfirmation
class SignupForm {

    static final String NOT_BLANK_MESSAGE = "{notBlank.message}"
    static final String UNIQUE_USERNAME_MESSAGE = "{uniqueUsername.message}"
    static final String EMAIL_MESSAGE = "{username.message}"
    static final String UNIQUE_EMAIL_MESSAGE = "{uniqueEmail.message}"

    @UniqueUsername
    @NotBlank(message = SignupForm.NOT_BLANK_MESSAGE)
    String username

    @UniqueEmail
    @NotBlank(message = SignupForm.NOT_BLANK_MESSAGE)
    @Email(message = SignupForm.EMAIL_MESSAGE)
    String email

    @NotBlank(message = SignupForm.NOT_BLANK_MESSAGE)
    String password

    @NotBlank(message = SignupForm.NOT_BLANK_MESSAGE)
    String confirmPassword


    User createAccount() {
        new User(username: email, email: email, password: password, role: ROLE_USER)
    }
}
```

PasswordConfirmation validation annotation :

```
package core.validation

import javax.validation.Constraint
import javax.validation.Payload
import java.lang.annotation.Retention
import java.lang.annotation.Target

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME

@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = PasswordConfirmationValidator)
@interface PasswordConfirmation {

    String message() default "{core.signup.validation.passwordConfirmation.message}"

    Class<?>[] groups() default []

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default []
}
```

Password confirmation validator :

```
package core.validation

import core.model.SignupForm
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext

@Slf4j
class PasswordConfirmationValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PasswordConfirmation, SignupForm> {

    @Override
    void initialize(PasswordConfirmation constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    boolean isValid(SignupForm form, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        log.info "password : ${form.password}"
        log.info "confirmPassword : ${form.confirmPassword}"
        println "password : ${form.password}"
        println "confirmPassword : ${form.confirmPassword}"
        println "defaultConstraintMessageTemplate : ${context.defaultConstraintMessageTemplate}"
        form.password.equals form.confirmPassword
    }
}
```

the thymeleaf view signup.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <title th:text="#{view.signup.title}">Inscription</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link href="../../../resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"
      th:href="@{/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    <link href="../../../resources/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" th:href="@{/resources/css/core.css}"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" th:src="@{/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div th:replace="fragments/header_signup :: header">Header</div>
<form class="form-narrow form-horizontal" method="post"
  th:action="@{/signup}" th:object="${signupForm}">
    <!-- /* Show general error message when form contains errors */ -->
    <th:block th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('${signupForm.*}')}">
        <div th:replace="fragments/alert :: alert (type='danger', message='Form contains errors. Please try again.')">
            Alert
        </div>
    </th:block>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}? 'has-error'">
            <label for="username" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Username</label>

            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" th:field="*{username}"/>
                <span class="help-block" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}"
                  th:errors="*{username}">Incorrect username</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}? 'has-error'">
            <label for="email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>

            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email address" th:field="*{email}"/>
                <span class="help-block" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}"
                  th:errors="*{email}">Incorrect email</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}? 'has-error'">
            <label for="password" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>

            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password"
                   th:field="*{password}"/>
                <span class="help-block" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}">Incorrect password</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('confirmPassword')}? 'has-error'">
            <label for="confirmPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password confirmation</label>

            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Password confirmation"
                   th:field="*{confirmPassword}"/>
                <!--how to show classe level constraint validation-->
                <span class="help-block" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('confirmPassword')}" th:errors="*{confirmPassword}">Incorrect password confirmation</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" th:text="#{view.signup.label}">Sign up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: shot in the dark: are they in global? http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/thymeleafspring.html#global-errors

Comment: @cfrick thanks a lot for having pinting me on this part of the documentation and even if it was a shot in the dark, you hit the right spot

Answer (score 2):

In order to show a class level constraint message I succeeded by using the global constant, like in the updated html code as shown in the [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/thymeleafspring.html#global-errors)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:text="#{view.signup.title}">Inscription</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link href="../../../resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"
      th:href="@{/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    <link href="../../../resources/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" th:href="@{/resources/css/core.css}"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" th:src="@{/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="fragments/header_signup :: header">Header</div>
<form class="form-narrow form-horizontal" method="post"
  th:action="@{/signup}" th:object="${signupForm}">
    <!-- /* Show general error message when form contains errors */ -->
    <th:block th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('${signupForm.*}')}">
        <div th:replace="fragments/alert :: alert (type='danger', message='Form contains errors. Please try again.')">
        Alert
        </div>
    </th:block>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}? 'has-error'">
            <label for="username" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Username</label>

            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" th:field="*{username}"/>
                <span class="help-block" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}"
                  th:errors="*{username}">Incorrect username</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}? 'has-error'">
            <label for="email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>

            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email address" th:field="*{email}"/>
                <span class="help-block" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}"
                  th:errors="*{email}">Incorrect email</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}? 'has-error'">
            <label for="password" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>

            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password"
                   th:field="*{password}"/>
                <span class="help-block" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}">Incorrect password</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('confirmPassword')}? 'has-error'">
            <label for="confirmPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password confirmation</label>

            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Password confirmation"
                   th:field="*{confirmPassword}"/>
                <span class="help-block" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('confirmPassword')}" th:errors="*{confirmPassword}">Incorrect password confirmation</span>
                <span class="help-block" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('global')}" th:errors="*{global}">Incorrect password confirmation</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" th:text="#{view.signup.label}">Sign up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```